# JavaScript smooth scroll - iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mootools, scroll

Are there any plugins or does anyone know of a good way to achieve the iPhone elastic band scroll?
working example in flash
http://www.shinedraw.com/text-effect/silverlight-3-and-flash-iphone-dragging-effect/

I'm looking to drag and scroll a div, but if it goes past a certain point it bounces back.

Thanks

Comment: eh, i wouldn't use mootools, I would use Jquery if I were you, much faster, more plugins, just all around better.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have figured out how to scroll it, it's very simple in mootools to obtain that "bounce" effect.

For example, you can apply a particular bounce effect in this way:

```
//element is supposed to be the main div you want to drag on iPhone
var element = $('elementID');

//instantiate a morph fx referred to that element
var bounceEffect = new Fx.Morph(element,{duration:1000, transition:Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut});

//...then, when you want it to bounce back (e.g. at the release, or when it goes below a certain position) you can do:

bounceEffect.start({'top':0});
```

Edit: take a look @ [mootouch](http://dailyjs.com/2010/03/24/mootouch/) too, it's a very interesting project

Answer (score 1):

Drew McCormack wrote an article for MacResearch about the physics of the bounce and momentum scrolling [here](http://www.macresearch.org/dynamics-scrolling), which includes JavaScript code for replicating much of the behavior you see on the iPhone.